# Strange Error ... Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'www.com' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, join, select, errors, type-conversion

The issue that I am running into is happening on Microsoft SQL Server.

I have a view that is unioning together 2 tables.  It is returning a little over 7 million records.

When I attempt to JOIN together the view with another table on one column I am getting an error: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'www.com' to data type int"
Example code:

View_A:

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, …, ColumnZ
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, …, ColumnZ
FROM Table2
```

***This SELECT is returning a Conversion failed error:***

```
SELECT * FROM View_A (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN Table3 (NOLOCK) ON View_A .ColumnA = Table3.ColumnA
```

**The ColumnA’s in all three tables are of type INT.**

*If I do one of the following, I get no errors:*

1. `SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM ViewA (NOLOCK)` and then do the JOIN on Table3
2. `SELECT * FROM View_A (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN Table3 (NOLOCK) ON TRY_CAST(View_A .ColumnA AS INT) = Table3.ColumnA`

***Any ideas on what is happening and how to fix would be greatly appreciated.***

Comment: I blame `NOLOCK` ;)

Comment: What are the types of columns B, C, ...Z? Do they match? My bet would one one of the column pairs having different types.

Comment: In addition to what ypercube said, also make sure you didn't accidentally leave out a comma between one of the columns such that it's treating the proceeding column as an alias. E.g. `SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB ColumnC` results in ColumnB being called ColumnC actually.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). But if you do, AT LEAST use the current syntax and not the deprecated syntax.

Comment: I can put in readuncommitted if you prefer :).  That aside, the query has been working for many years and all of a sudden it started to error.  As far as I know, nothing has changed query wise.  So, the columns match up.  The really strange thing, as I mentioned, I can run it using the two methods and not get an error.

Comment: OK let's have the full table schemas and the *full* query. Also the full definition of `View_A`. I'm confused why you think that unioning an `int` and a `varchar` without `try_cast` wouldn't return an error

Answer (score 1):

Something, somewhere is doing an implicit conversion. Since int has a [higher precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) than varchar the string "www.com" is being cast to int and failing.

First try a simple `select * from view_a`. Does that succeed? If it does it suggest table1 and table2 have compatible data types in their corresponding columns.

Second check the types assigned to columns of #TempTable. Are they what is expected?

Then check `select * from view_A where TRY_CAST(View_A.ColumnA AS INT) is null`. Are any rows returned? If so the view's column A is not what you think investigate that.

TRY_CAST returns NULL if the [cast fails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql). I would expect rows that do not cast correctly to be omitted from the join in your second "I've tried".

If there's still no resolution create copies of tables 1, 2 and 3 with just column A. Do the views and queries work then? If so add back further columns, perhaps a few at a time if there are many, and repeat until the error is thrown.